# What are the common words for "clean" and "dirty", "tidy" and "untidy"?

Tags: translation, word-requests, antonyms

For example, how do Chinese speakers normally say:

1. Your room is so clean!
2. Your room is so dirty!
3. Your room is so tidy!
4. Your room is so untidy!

脏 Is this the most common way to say dirty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @Tang Ho's answer but I'd like to add something here.

Orally, people tend to skip the word "的" and may use "好" instead of "真".

```
1. Your room is so clean! 你房间好干净啊。
2. Your room is so dirty! 你房间好脏啊。
3. Your room is so tidy! 你房间好整洁啊。
4. Your room is so untidy! 你房间好乱啊。
```

Note that I added a modal word "啊" at the end of each sentence. This is because there is a slight difference between "好" and "真".

"好" is a milder tone and the speaker is trying to address their feeling about the cleanness or tidiness of your room. If the speaker uses "真", the speaker emphasises more on the fact that the room is dirty.

And "脏" is the most common way to say dirty.

Answer (score 0):

“clean” -- 干净

“dirty”  -- 脏

“tidy” -- 整洁

“untidy” -- 邋遢、凌乱

Answer (score 0):

1. Your room is **so clean**! - 你的房间**真干净**！
2. Your room is **so dirty**! -  你的房间**真脏**！/ 你的房间**真肮脏**！
3. Your room is **so tidy!** - 你的房间**真整洁**！
4. Your room is **so untidy**! - 你的房间**真不整洁**！/ 你的房间**真凌乱**！/你的房间**真乱**！

> 脏 Is this the most common way to say dirty?

Yes, 脏 or 肮脏 is the most common way to say 'dirty' when it comes to describing a room or place. It can also describe object, thought or deed

other term for dirty include:

污穢 (place, thought or deed)

嗱喳/揦鮓/揦苴(laa5 zaa2), 邋遢(la1 ta1), 污糟(wu1 zou1) are all Cantonese only

Comment: It is rare that people would say "不整洁" or "凌乱", unless they find the room is extremely untidy and feel a single word "乱" is insufficient to express themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Your room is spotless! 你的房间一尘不染。

Your room is disgusting! 你的房间真恶心。

Your room is so neat and tidy! 你的屋子井然有序！

Your room is soooo untidy, there's not even anywhere to stand!

你的房间乱得连下脚的地方都没有。

Your room is a total mess! 你的房间一团糟！